# Flashplugin-installer errors

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, flash, synaptic

I have installed `flashplugin-installer` through Synaptic and before have tried `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` in LXTerminal, and whenever I load Google Chrome/Chromium and navigate to a site with ANYTHING flash I get an error message saying "Could not load Shockwave Flash." Any help? (I'm running Lubuntu 12.10 when I get these error messages. They didn't appear for me when using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS before I switched to Lubuntu for performance reasons.)

Comment: try: `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras`

Comment: @nickanor I ran that command when I first logged on, but thanks anyway C:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try: install FIREFOX browser and FLASH-AID plugin. Then run Flash-aid and it will install the software. Hope this works.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me.